# Spring Cloud Gateway - 404 Not Found Error

Tags: java, spring-cloud-gateway

I am working on Spring Cloud Gateway. I developed the implementation, but spring cloud gateway returns 404 Not found. I am pretty new for spring-cloud-gateway. Everything seems really correct, but I am getting 404 not found error.

Here is application.yml.

```
      spring:
    application:
      name: gtw-partner-svc
      main:
        web-application-type: reactive
    cloud:
      gateway:
        httpclient:
          ssl:
            use-insecure-trust-manager: true
        discovery:
          locator:
            enabled: true
            lowerCaseServiceId: true
  
  route:
    config:
      allowedPaths:
        - "/callback/**"
        - "/actuator/info"
        - "/actuator/health"
      hostDetails:
        onb-veriff-svc: ${ONB_VERIFF_SVC_URL:http://localhost:7000}
```

Here is RouteLocator bean.

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class GatewayRoutes {

private final RouteConfigurationProperties routeConfigurationProperties;
private final VeriffServiceRoutes veriffServiceRoutes;

@Bean
RouteLocator serviceRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return ServiceRouteDefinition.setupRoutes(
                    builder,
                    routeConfigurationProperties,
                    Set.of(veriffServiceRoutes))
            .build();
}
```

}

Here is my route definition.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class VeriffServiceRoutes implements ServiceRouteDefinition {

private static final String VERIFF_ADAPTER = "onb-veriff-svc";
private static final String X_SIGNATURE = "x-signature";
private static final String X_AUTH_CLIENT = "x-auth-client";

@Override
public Map<String, Function<PredicateSpec, Buildable<Route>>> getRouteDefinitions(RouteConfigurationProperties properties) {
    return Map.of(VERIFF_ADAPTER, veriffWebHookRoute(properties));
}

private Function<PredicateSpec, Buildable<Route>> veriffWebHookRoute(RouteConfigurationProperties properties) {
    return route -> route.path("/callback/veriff/**")
            .and().header(X_SIGNATURE)
            .and().header(X_AUTH_CLIENT)
            .and().method(HttpMethod.POST)
            .and().readBody(String.class, requestBody -> true)
            .filters(filter -> filter
                    .rewritePath("/callback/veriff/events", "/events")
                    .rewritePath("/callback/veriff/decision", "/decision"))
            .uri(getURIHost(properties, VERIFF_ADAPTER));
}
```

}

Here is base pom.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.gtw.partner</groupId>
<artifactId>gtw-partner-parent</artifactId>
<version>${revision}</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <revision>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</revision>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
    <junit-jupiter.version>5.5.1</junit-jupiter.version>
    <assertj.version>3.11.1</assertj.version>
    <commons-lang3.version>3.9</commons-lang3.version>
    <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.8.8</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
    <sonar-maven-plugin.version>3.9.1.2184</sonar-maven-plugin.version>
    <sonar-jacoco-listeners.version>5.14.0.18788</sonar-jacoco-listeners.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-jacoco-listeners</artifactId>
            <version>${sonar-jacoco-listeners.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${sonar-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <updatePomFile>true</updatePomFile>
                <flattenMode>resolveCiFriendliesOnly</flattenMode>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>flatten</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>flatten</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>flatten.clean</id>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<modules>
    <module>gtw-partner-svc</module>
</modules>
```

Here is pom.xml for service layer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.gtw.partner</groupId>
    <artifactId>gtw-partner-parent</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>gtw-partner-svc</artifactId>
<name>gtw-partner-svc</name>
<description>gateway partner service</description>

<properties>
    <git-commit-id-plugin.version>3.0.0</git-commit-id-plugin.version>
    <logbook.version>2.14.0</logbook.version>
    <auth0-jwt.version>4.2.1</auth0-jwt.version>
    <reactor-test.version>3.2.10.RELEASE</reactor-test.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- SPRING DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
        <artifactId>logbook-spring-boot-webflux-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>${logbook.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>${auth0-jwt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- TEST DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <version>${reactor-test.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>app</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- mvn clean verify sonar:sonar -Pcoverage -->
        <id>coverage</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.java</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-jacoco-listeners</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Specific to generate mapping between tests and covered code -->
                        <properties>
                            <property>
                                <name>listener</name>
                                <value>org.sonar.java.jacoco.JUnitListener</value>
                            </property>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <!--
                            Prevents Jacoco from instrumenting GraphQL generated classes.
                            Jacoco throws IllegalArgumentException when it instruments graphql generated classes.
                            https://github.com/apache/incubator-skywalking/pull/1085
                            -->
                            <exclude>*MethodAccess</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>agent</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>report</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

[image]

Comment: did'nt forget You  about annotations? recently I also faced this issue and i forgot to put '@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableZuulProxy' annotations becouse of I tired to upgrade version from 2.7 to 3.o